# Замена несущесвуещего значения в JSON на 0

Tags: python, json

Дело вот такое. Код делает http запрос на сайт с форматом JSON.
P.S В JSON содержится статистика игрока. 
Например если  у игрока нету побед то в JSON это просто не прописыватся.
Как мне отоброзить в консоли что побед 0? Потомучто если делать просто то выдаёт ошибку KeyEroor.

Answer (score 3):

Обращайтесь к ключу не через [], а методом get. Тогда KeyEroor отступит.

```
player_wins = my_data_dict.get(my_key, 0);
```

Вторым аргументом указывается значение по умолчанию, 0 в нашем случае.

Comment: Не работает, язык программирования Python.

Comment: Методы словарей https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html